# ES6 : "Import React from 'react' " statement does not work for me

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to learn React.js, but when I import it, it doesn't work and I get this error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "react". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

It doesn't seem right, as normal importations usually work with the "Import React from 'react' " statement.

This is my main.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
    const element = React.createElement('div', {}, React.createElement('h1', {}, 'Hello React ! '), React.createElement('p', {}, 'Test paragraph to learn React ! '))
    return element;
}

const root = document.getElementById('root');
const container = ReactDOM.createRoot(root);
container.render(App);
```

And this is my html page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Title here</title>
        <script src="main.js" type="module" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <article>
            <h2>React</h2>
            <div id="root"></div>
        </article>

        <noscript>
            <p>You need JavaScript for this page.</p>
        </noscript>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried several different approaches, such as directly linking to the exact file in node_modules, but it just told me there was no default export.

What to do ? Should I just use the CDN ?

Comment: Have you installed the `react` dependency? What is the contents of your package.json?

Comment: Are you using Webpack? Raw imports need a full path. Webpack looks in predefined locations for modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, unless your using some bundler, eg. webpack, rollup, vite etc.  `import React from "react";` cannot be used.   A CDN can be used, but make sure it's ES module compatible.

eg.

```html
<script type="module">
  import * as React from "https://esm.sh/react";      
  console.log(React.version);  
</script>
```

> Note:
>
> Saying the above, React does work best when using a bundler,
> mainly down to been able to use JSX syntax, browsers have no knowledge
> of JSX, but bunders can transpile JSX into a form React understands. And if your into Typescript, you can also use TSX, again
> something browsers don't understand.